# Start activity inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment-tab-host

I got how create a tabhost using Fragment, like the photo below

[image]

"Fragment_container" is changed when clicking the tabs below the screen, and will be linking to fragment 1 to 4 respectively.

That's all I have achieved currently, and now what I want to do is

[image]

My purpose is, I don't know am I using the terms correctly, every fragment is like a single activity, I can start activity inside that fragment, just like above photo, with transition animation and without disappearing the tabhost. (Actually I'm using iOS, not often using Android, is it possible in Android?)

I've tried :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment5.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It starts activity successfully, but the tabhost disappears.

```
Fragment newFragment = new Fragment5();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Basically works, but is there only one way? any efficient solutions else for my case?

Comment: after trying it wht you got ?

Comment: "Fragment_container" is changed to Fragment5 successfully, with no transition animation. It's much setContentView(), thing I want is when starting Fragment5 on Tab1 (Fragment1), Fragment1 is still running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Normal because the tab host that you created belong only for that activity you should create a new tab host for the new activity and add the corresponding fragment on top

i hope it was you meant and that it helped you!

Edit: and no fragment are not activity they are meant to be bind with activity and they have their own cycle. unless you want to extend your fragment as ActivityFragment.

if im wrong hope someone will correct me

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you meant, can I have any code example?

Comment: dUde waht you did so far is to replace the current activity contentView which is all fragment from 1 to 4 plus the tab to fragment 5... what you should do is create another activiy and recreate your tab host inside activity2 then add fragment 5
example: Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class)
the start it with startActivity(intent);

Comment: I have 1 main activity and 4 fragments. Main activity includes a tab host linking to fragment1-4. Did you mean, I need to create another activity including the tab host which appeared in main activity, and only add fragment on that activity?

Comment: If yes, it should not be so efficient? Things I am going to do is treating those 4 fragments as individual activity, as fragment 1 is search function then all search actions (result after search, click results and etc.) is running on tab1 (fragment1). Instagram's effect is much like my purpose.